# Function for a transpose of a 3x3 matrix in c

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function to transpose a matrix (Adjugate matrix). I tried different things but it still crashes. Do you have any ideas what could be the problem?

P.S I call that function with `adjoint(a, b);`

P.S.S The purpose of the whole program is to create an inverse of a matrix.

**Edited code**
(showing bigger part of the code and pointing functions which may cause the crashing of the program)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 3 //defining the size of the matrix (3x3)
#define SIZE2 2 //defining the size of the matrix (2x2)


//prototyping the functions used to calculate the inverse of the matrix
void readMatrix(double a[SIZE][SIZE]);
void printMatrix(double a[SIZE][SIZE]);
void printMinorMatrix(double b[SIZE2][SIZE2]);
void selecting(double a[SIZE][SIZE], double b[SIZE2][SIZE2]);
double calculating(double a[SIZE][SIZE],double m[8]);
void anArray(double m[8]);
double convert(double m[8], double [SIZE][SIZE]);
double determ(double m[8], double n[SIZE][SIZE]);
double adjoint(double a[SIZE][SIZE],double b[SIZE][SIZE]);
double multiplyMatrix(double a[SIZE][SIZE], double b[SIZE][SIZE], double 
result[SIZE][SIZE]);

int main()
{
    double a[SIZE][SIZE];
    double b[SIZE2][SIZE2];
    double m[8];
    double n[SIZE][SIZE];
    double d;
    double q[SIZE][SIZE];
    int i,j,k;



    printf("Adjoint of the Matrix:\n");
    printf("_________________________________________\n\n");
    adjoint(a,b);
    printf("\n\n");


    printf("Scalar Multiplication:\n");
    printf("_________________________________________\n\n");
    multiplyMatrix(i,j,k);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}




//Reading a 3x3 Matrix
void readMatrix(double a[SIZE][SIZE])


//Printing a 3x3 Matrix
void printMatrix(double a[SIZE][SIZE])


//Printing a 2x2 Matrix
void printMinorMatrix(double b[SIZE2][SIZE2])


//Selecting a 2x2 Matrix from a 3x3 Matrix
void selecting(double a[SIZE][SIZE],double b[SIZE2][SIZE2])


//Calculating the determinant of a 2x2 matrix
double calculating(double a[SIZE][SIZE], double m[8])



//Printing an Array of Length 9
void anArray(double m[8])


//Calculating the determinant of a 3x3 matrix
double determ(double m[8], double n[SIZE][SIZE])


//Converting an Array into a Matrix
double convert(double m[8], double K[3][3])



//Transposing a Matrix
double adjoint(double a[SIZE][SIZE],double b[SIZE][SIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            if(i!=j&&i<j)
                {
                      b[i][j]=a[j][i];
                }
           else b[i][j]= a[i][j];
    }
    return b[SIZE][SIZE];
}

//Scalar multiplication
double multiplyMatrix(double a[SIZE][SIZE], double b[SIZE][SIZE], double result[SIZE][SIZE])
{
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            result[i][j]=0.0;

            for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++){
                result[i][j] += a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `if(i!=j&&i<j)` can be written `if(i<j)`

Comment: change `return b[SIZE][SIZE]` to `return b[SIZE -1 ][SIZE -1 ]`. But why you want to  return a value. Your purpose is served even without doing that.

Comment: Post the complete code to an example program that shows the problem

Comment: @chqrlie That is the complete code: https://pastebin.com/uAmNKxvf

Comment: OK, then remove code from your example until the problem can no longer be reproduced and post the code to the previous step in your question.

Comment: @chqrlie you mean to post my whole code in my description? Because I once did that and I got the answer that stackoverflow is not a debugging service.. ;d

Comment: What @chqrlie means is to to study and follow [mcve].

Comment: I mean post the code to a **minimal** example that has the problem you describe. The complete code is more than 400 lines, so of course do not post that. Remove functions that are not necessary to display the problem. You should end up with a much smaller piece of code where the bug will be easier to locate.  GAURANGVYAS already spotted a real bug, there are probably other similar ones in the rest of your code.

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of the adjoint function is? From the code and the question title, I would guess that you make a copy of a in b, just transposed. However why only for `i<j`? And what is the purpose of retutning anything? Your example how you call it `adjoint(a, b);`might mean you are ignoring the retun value. If you could make a [mcve] (cheers chqrlie), we would be able to derive some answer to our worries from that.

Comment: Just to agree on a term:  "transposing" a matrix means for example turning "[1,2][3,4]" into "[1,3][2,4]", true? Could you show serval diffrent examples of sample input and the output/result of calling your function on them?

Comment: A MCVE would also show more context of how ou call it. You do not for example call it with two pointers referencing the same matrix, do you?

Comment: If you ignore the return value which accesses out of bounds of the matrix, then you better change the function to `void adjoint()` and return nothing.

Comment: What you've posted has too many function declarations and too many incomplete functions in it.  You should remove all the functions for which you don't show the implementation.  Your question title asks about transpose; the code showed the `adjoint` function.  Is the adjoint matrix also the transpose?  You also mention adjugate matrix — am I that badly out of touch with matrices?  (Wikipedia on [Ajugate Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) — I think you have some terminology problems.  (See MCVE — [MCVE].)

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings for feeding an array[2][2] into a parameter which wants an array[3][3]? No? Not even with `gcc -Wall`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
return b[SIZE][SIZE];
```

You are returning a value that does not exist. Last in-bounds value is

```
return b[SIZE-1][SIZE-1];
```

---

Looking at the whole code, you have many warnings to sole before to execute your code...

The main one referred to the question is that.

b matrix passed to  `adjoint` function is **2x2 matrix**, instead of **3x3 matrix**.

In main you declared

```
double a[SIZE][SIZE];
double b[SIZE2][SIZE2];
```

where

```
#define SIZE 3 //defining the size of the matrix (3x3)
#define SIZE2 2 //defining the size of the matrix (2x2)
```

Comment: You are probably right.  I changed that, but unfortunately it still does not work ;//

Comment: @JohnSmith If this does not work then error could be in some other part of code. Please post the complete relevant code.

Comment: When I run the program and I get until the point where that function is in process the program shows a message "Matrix.exe has stopped working" (crashes). Just fyi, that function is part of a program which creates an inverse of a matrix (i am not sure whether that is important or not).